# Google Colab, unable to upload zipped file (3gb file)

Tags: file-upload, google-colaboratory, drive

I have a 3gb zipfile containing folders for training a model(Images and text documents). I compressed the files and ready to put them in colab:
[image]

But when i try to upload the file it shows up as a red circle isntead of loading. I dont understand what I am doing wrong. I would doubt its the size as it seems I have a 50gb capacity.

I tried by uplaoding by just dragging, clicking the upload button, I tried to even send part of the file, but im still getting this error.

Please help.

[image]
[image]